# Page for a decommissioned Collective has no <title>

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

On a [page for a decommissioned Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go), the page's `<title>` is empty:

```html
<title></title>
```

As a result, the title for the window/tab is just the URL of the page. The page should have a title.

Comment: *Should* it though? Why isn't the URL enough here?  What is the chance that someone is going to have a tab open to this collective, let alone have a bad UX in not knowing what it is (or was)?

Comment: "No titles for the old Collectives"

Comment: Yep, that's an oversight on our part. We'll get that fixed shortly.

Comment: Ironically(?), the HTML tag in this post's title caused our internal issue (generated by the [status-review] tag being added to this post) to simply be titled: `Page for a decommissioned Collective has no`

Comment: I thought that edit might shake out even more bugs, @V2Blast! :-) Let that be a lesson to you and yours: always sanitize and escape your inputs. (But [only once this time plzkthx](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377743).)

Comment: @V2Blast it is a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377970/already-approved-pending-edit-goes-br#comment1261626_377970) that html in titles causes problems with the issue tracker (or at least it was a problem in April, maybe now html is just stripped completely as a fix, while a better fix would be to keep the tag but not render it as html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this.  I've deployed a fix so that the page has a Title element matching the page headline.

[image: screenshot showing Title element matching page header]